# Graph python similar to R

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a table like this one: (Ignore the columns "Index" and "D")

```
+-------+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Index |         Type          |   Male   |  Female  |    D     |
+-------+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    44 | Life struggles        | 2.097324 | 3.681356 | 1.584032 |
|     2 | Writing notes         | 2.677262 | 3.354730 | 0.677468 |
|    18 | Empathy               | 3.528117 | 4.083051 | 0.554933 |
|    12 | Criminal damage       | 2.926650 | 2.374150 | 0.552501 |
|    20 | Giving                | 2.650367 | 3.196944 | 0.546577 |
|    21 | Compassion to animals | 3.666667 | 4.178268 | 0.511602 |
|    33 | Mood swings           | 2.965937 | 3.451613 | 0.485676 |
|    10 | Funniness             | 3.574572 | 3.104907 | 0.469665 |
|    38 | Children              | 3.354523 | 3.805415 | 0.450891 |
|    47 | Small - big dogs      | 3.221951 | 2.801695 | 0.420256 |
+-------+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and I am trying to do a similar graph : [image]

I know how to do it in R but not in python

I tried this:

```
sns.stripplot(data=df,y="Male",color="Blue")
sns.stripplot(data=df,y="Female",color="red")
```

[image]

But I don't know how to continue. Does someone have am idea?

Comment: Take a look at the [plotnine](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine) library from python. It is supposed to be a python implementation of ggplot

Comment: Manipulating the plot both in `seaborn` and in `matplotlib` you can achieve something similar. Go to the webpages and start trying. Otherwise, try `plotnine` as @luizgg said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done with matplotlib, it is simply a scatter plot with categories as y-values.

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['Male'],df['Type'],'o', color='xkcd:reddish', ms=10, label='Male')
ax.plot(df['Female'],df['Type'],'o', color='xkcd:teal', ms=10, label='Female')
ax.axvline(3,ls='-',color='k')

ax.set_xlim(1,5)
ax.set_xlabel('avg response')
ax.set_ylabel('Variable')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.02), loc='lower center',
           ncol=2, title='group')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh looks great. Thanks you so much!